# QUnit test not working on assert.throws()

Tags: sapui5, qunit

Maybe i don't understand [the documentation](https://api.qunitjs.com/assert/throws/), my test is not working.

I'll **test an expected error** from a function:

```js
// file_to_test.js
...
myFunctionToTest: function(param1, param2 = "AA-BB") {
  const idx1 = param2.indexOf("AA");
  if(idx1 === -1) {
    throw new Error('test message error');
  }
}
```

here comes **the test**:

```js
// test.js
sap.ui.define(["path/to/my/script"], function(myScriptToTest) {
  ...
  QUnit.test('should thrown error', assert => {
    assert.throws(
      function() {
        myScriptToTest.myFunctionToTest('blabla', 'blubblub'); // test is broken at this line
      },
      function(error) {
        return error.toString() === 'test message error';
      },
      'Error thrown'
    }
  })
})
```

The return (Browser-)output:

```
1. Error thrown
Expected:   function( a ){
  [code]
}
  Result: Error("test message error")
  Diff: function( a ){
          [code]
        }Error("test message error")
Source: ...
```

**How to setup the test** correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Your QUnit code looks fine, but there is a mistake in how you've written your JavaScript logic.

It is actually true that `error.toString()` does not equal `test message error`. What you're looking for is `error.message` and not `error.toString()`.

Consider the following:

```js
var myerror = new Error('hello world');
console.log(myerror.toString());
// 'Error: hello world'
console.log(myerror.toString() === 'hello world');
// false

console.log('-------');

console.log(myerror.message);
// 'hello world'
console.log(myerror.message === 'hello world');
// true
```

See also:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors
- https://api.qunitjs.com/assert/throws/